# run database migration through a k8s job

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, database-migration, jobs, alembic

I want to run database migration via a job in k8s. The database is located in a mariadb pod in the same cluster, installed through bitnami/mariadb helm chart. So I think the mariadb can be seen/exposed as a service.

How can I let migration pod connect to the mariadb pod? It seems I cannot connect to the database well in the migration pod, even if I have configured the mariadb host in the migration pod image. When I run `alembic upgrade head`, it just hangs there, no any output.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you tell more about your setup? How exactly your `Service` that expose your `mariadb` looks like? How exactly your `Job` looks like? How exactly are you trying to connect to your `mariadb`?